# p:tree setSelectedNodes from another form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PF 3.4 and JSF2. (I altered the showcase example to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.)

The xhtml file (with an extra commandButton in a second form):

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" escape="false"/>
    <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
        selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{treeBean.selectedNodes}"  id="treeMultiple">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

    <p:commandButton value="Display Selected" update="messages"
        actionListener="#{treeBean.displaySelectedMultiple}" id="btnDisplay" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <p:commandButton value="Display Selected" 
        process=":form:treeMultiple"
        actionListener="#{treeBean.displaySelectedMultiple}" id="btnDisplay2" />
</h:form>
```

The Backing Bean:

```
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
private TreeNode root;
private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;

public TreeBean() {
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
    TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
    TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);
    TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);

    TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
    TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

    TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);
    TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);

    TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);
    TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);
    TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);

    TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);
}

public TreeNode getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public TreeNode[] getSelectedNodes() {
    return selectedNodes;
}

public void setSelectedNodes(TreeNode[] selectedNodes) {
    this.selectedNodes = selectedNodes;
}

public void displaySelectedMultiple(ActionEvent event) {
    if(selectedNodes != null && selectedNodes.length > 0) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(TreeNode node : selectedNodes) {
            builder.append(node.getData().toString());
            builder.append("<br />");
        }

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", builder.toString());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

}

The problem I'm having is with the setSelectedNodes method in the backing bean.

The commandButton, :form2:btnDisplay2, will invoke the method, however, it passes a TreeNode[0] value (empty array). It's not passing the selected nodes correctly.

The first button, :form:btnDisplay, works correctly.

**Additional Info:**
In my application, I have "filters" in the left nav area (form1): date ranges, and various criteria that will narrow the search - these are all optional. Some of these criteria are in a p:tree component. I currently have an "Apply Filters" button in that form which works: the p:tree selections are passed to the backing bean correctly.

In the main content area (form2), I have the required selection criteria (account#) and a "SEARCH" button. The problem is that the users forget to click the "Apply Filters" button from form1. They set the date ranges, and checkboxes in the p:tree (in form1), then click the "SEARCH" button on form2.

So, from form2, I'm trying to process the p:tree from form1.

Comment: put the second button in the same form.

Comment: seriously? it's a <ui:composition> where form1 is in a different <ui:define> segment than form2.

Comment: I tried to phrase my question clearly, but maybe I fell short. Thanks @Nick Hol for at least giving me the suggestion. No one has any other ideas? comments? insults?